# How to link subdomains to main domain to get SEO benefit

Tags: seo, subdomain

How can I link subdomains to my main domain to get the SEO benefit? I've seen examples using all sorts of clever redirects and PHP where you get the subdomain's content on the main site...but what I want is for the subdomain to be linked with the main domain; I don't mind it sitting by itself, but I'd just like to get the SEO benefit of it. I'm aware that Google see subdomains as separate domains but can change / help them to be seen more as one site?

Comment: Subdomains are not seen as separate domains.

Comment: really ? does it not see them as separate domains on a backlink level ie. if i get a link to my sub domain it wont benefit the main domain..

Comment: All links benefit the page they are linking to, but a subdomain is considered to be part of the main domain/website.

Answer (score 3):

See [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

Here what [Google's Matt Cutts has to say about sub-domains vs folders](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/)

> My personal preference on subdomains vs. subdirectories is that I usually prefer the convenience of subdirectories for most of my content. A subdomain can be useful to separate out content that is completely different. Google uses subdomains for distinct products such news.google.com or maps.google.com, for example. If you’re a newer webmaster or SEO, I’d recommend using subdirectories until you start to feel pretty confident with the architecture of your site. At that point, you’ll be better equipped to make the right decision for your own site.

Here is what [Rand Fishkin from SEOMoz says about sub-domains vs folders](http://www.seomoz.org/q/subdomains-vs-subfolders)

> Subdomains SOMETIMES inherit and pass link/trust/quality/ranking metrics between one another
>
> Subfolders ALWAYS inherit and pass link/trust/quality/ranking metrics across the same subdomain

Google will *automatically* treat the subdomain as part of the main domain *if* it thinks they are part of the same site and run by the same person or company.  Here are some signals that you can use to make it easy for Google to see that they are part of the same site and run by the same person:

- Interlink the main site and the subdomain.    Separate sites don't typically interlink.
- Use the same copyright statement on both.
- Use the same "about" page and privacy policy links in the footer.
- Register both in Google Webmaster Tools.   This shows that the same author has access to both.
- Get HTTPS certificates for each of them (or use the same wild card certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Since March 2014 Google no longer sees subdomains as part of the main domain. Essentially they treat each subdomain as a seperate website. As far as I know you can't get the SEO benefits of your subdomains to your main domain, other than having some referring links between them.

Answer (score -2):

It will be regarded as cheat by search engine that if the same site has various subdomains.

Comment: For example Wikipedia...

Answer (score -2):

You have to just create hyperlink with your keyword in sub domain page and give link of main page. You must have to keep limit up to 1-2 links from sub domain to main page because more linking seems spamming and it will definitely detect by Search engine.