# Changing image upload directory

Tags: images, directory

A couple of years ago I changed my websites upload directory to a subdomain (to images.mudfooted.com). I am now working on a major update on my website and wondering if the subdomain is actually the best option compared to a subdirectory (e.g. mudfooted.com/images). I get a lot of visitors via google images but am wondering if the hits to the images.mudfooted.com subdirectory only are not added to the mudfooted.com hits. I initially chose to use a subdirectory to increase the site loading speed.

So my question: Is it better to change the upload directory to a subdirectory or subdomain, taking loading time and SEO into account.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: What exactly is your question: about the SEO aspect?

Comment: Yes, is it better to host the images in a subdirectory instead of a subdomain for visitor statistics and SEO?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read the responses at [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34173/subdomains-vs-subdirectory-status-as-of-2012) for more detail but the general consensus is that it isn't going matter all that much either way.  Google tends to not distinguish a sudomain from a subdirectory except in special cases (WordPress.com, Tumblr, etc.).  If your traffic is in that range, you have a different set of issues :)