# Using subdomains for niche SEO

Tags: seo, subdomain

Simple question:

If I have a website offering website themes and I set up subdomains like builder.themes.com, artist.themes.com would that be more beneficial than having totally separate sites or less?

I know a subdomain is classed as its own site and doesn't inherit the main site's page rank but if these niches are all aimed at having a theme...what's best?

Comment: I would like to know it too.

Comment: You may find a good answer here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo that quotes a ex-Google employee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opinions are often different in this kind of opened question.

Personally, I prefer create categories on main website unlike subdomains in order to publish content (keywords) on main website.

Subdomains are hard to maintain and seo work has to be multiplied because there are different websites.

For me, subdomain are useful to create a blog for example but not for various website themes which speak about the same subject.