# Should I make sub-domain for different kind of content?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, subdomain

At this time I am running technology related blog and I'm tired of it because of writing only tech related articles, because of this reason I want to make a blog on sub-domain of root domain where I'll share stuff that I like and mostly stuff that make me feel good. Its content is totally going to be different from root domain's.
Is it secure to make another blog on sub-domain of my main blog or should I buy new domain name. Thing is, I want to stick with my old domain name.

I am going to make a sub-domain like this fun.domain.com

I read somewhere that Google treat sub-domains as spam. Because it could be used to takeover search results by making too much subdomains e.g. About.com have different sub-domains for different categories but Google don't take it as spam.

**Update:** Thanks for letting me know about another question about this topic. [Do subdomain help/hurt SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo). It answered my question but I want to know little more if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains are treated as separate URLs so this shouldn't be a problem. The main downside of organizing your blogs like this is that you will be building your page rank separately for each domain. Because the content is different for each one that isn't really a big problem. It will be better for the web to do it this way opposed to putting them all on one site because the searches that lead to your site will be more targeted. For the same reason, it may also lead to less overall hits.

Comment: Blog I'm going to make on subdomain is completly different from main.
Will this effect my old blog?

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate of this one has a much more complete answer than mine. I'd reference that for a better answer. The short answer to that question is 'No'. Assuming that your current site is the default (empty) sub domain on your site; your new domain can be affected by the fun.* domain but not vice versa.

Comment: This link has a lot more information (including some which directly contradicts what I've said): http://moz.com/learn/seo/domain

Comment: After rereading my first comment I noticed a typo. `fun.*` should read `parent`.

Comment: My old blog is on www subdomain i.e. www.domain.com