# New domain vs Subdomain vs new Folder for each new project

Tags: seo

If I have a domain like `http://example.com/` which would be the best to use for every new project I create. Would it be a subdomain `http://exampleprojectname.example.com/` or a new domain `http://exampleprojectname.com/` or a new folder `http://example.com/exampleprojectname`. Which one would be the best and good for seo.

Comment: There is already many questions and answers regarding the use of domains vs that of a sub directory or sub domain, please ensure you read the rules and faq before posting to avoid further disappointment. Additionally > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Do you want each project to perform well on their own (completely) or do you want support between them? If you want the project to compete completely on their own with little to no bleeding/support from one to the other, then you want a sub-domain. If they are to support each other and have some relative relationship, then you want a sub-directory.