# How to make Google consider subdomain as part of the main website in SEO?

Tags: seo, google, domains, subdomain, blog

I have a well ranked website on Google and Bing. In the last few months I've been feeding a blog for my webpage and now I'm trying to rank it on Google and Bing just like I did with my website.

Unfortunatelly, for some technical reasons, I can't set the blog URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/(posts-permalinks)
```

In that way, it would be considered as a part of the website. So, I use subdomains, like:

```
http://blog.example.com/(posts-permalinks)
```

As far as I know, Google considers them as different sites, but I wish I could tell Google that they're the same website.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google will automatically treat subdomains as part of the main site when:

- They have related content
- They are written by the same person or company
- They link to each other

From [Vanessa Fox](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/subdomains-or-subfolders-which-are-better-for-seo/6849/), an ex-Google employee:

> Google is no longer treating subdomains (blog.widgets.com versus widgets.com) independently, instead attaching some association between them. The ranking algorithms have been tweaked so that pages from multiple subdomains have a much higher relevance bar to clear in order to be shown.

Here is a list of things you can do from [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo):

- Link between the subdomain and the main site in the navigation menu, and visa-versa.
- Put the same copyright statement on the bottom of each
- Link each to the same terms of service, privacy policy, and contact page
- Use the same logo on each
- Use the same look and feel: colors, fonts, and layout
- Add the subdomain to the same account in Google Search Console
- Use the same Google Analytics and adversiting accounts (such as AdSense) on each