# How to properly link a blog to a website?

Tags: seo, links, blog, link-building

I've been twice in a situation where I had to create a blog alongside a website. We've decided to externalize the blogging platform to `wordpress.com` (no maintenance and security concerns, good features, cheap, etc.).

I wish I could use an `example.com/blog/` URL scheme, but it's not possible, so I chose `blog.example.com`.

I've been wondering how I could tell Google (and other crawlers) that those 2 are linked. There are `rel="me"` attributes on links, but it seems kind of thin.

Do you know any good way to "associate" 2 websites?

Comment: You can link your main domain from the blog as you want. By seeing the links, Google is capable of detecting the two are linked.

Comment: We already have bi-directional links, but they don't tell crawler anything different than a good old link exchange between two sites.

Comment: Google is smart enough to understand on its own. You don't need a special markup or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider reading [this](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/register-domain/) about registering your domiain so you could host your blog on your site.

Regarding search engine recognition, I suggest using [OG social snippets](http://ogp.me/) in you header, this will allow search engines and social networking site s to recognise your site more easily.
Just add these taggs before the `</head>` tag on your site.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR TITLE"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="YOUR IMAGE URL"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR URL" />
<meta property="og:description"content="YOUR DESCRIPTION" />
```

Comment: We already have OpenGraph metadata on both our site and our blog. They serve different purpose on each site, for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The menus on your main site should link to your blog, and the menus on your blog should link to your main site.  It is really that simple.

Since you blog is a subdomain of your main domain, it is very easy to get Google and other search engines to view it as part of your site.  See: [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)