# how sub domain can effect traffic of root domain

Tags: seo, subdomain, traffic, web-traffic

we have root domain of a university and every college of university has its own sub domain, just want to know how these domain can effect the traffic of the root domain, recently we did a web audit, auditor said sub domains are effecting root domain traffic, and how we can improve traffic of root domain

Comment: See this related recent question as well:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76263/can-a-subdomain-interfere-with-the-ranking-of-a-root-domain  And this regarding your last question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google

Comment: thanks for recommendation i will read those post and update

Comment: No problem. If your question was different from one of those, then just edit it so that it's clear and it will be placed in the review queue to be considered for reopening.