# Will a popular subdomain overshadow the main domain from an SEO perspective?

Tags: seo, subdomain

This question may have been asked multiple times. But, I couldn't find a solid solution, so thought of posting it here.

I have a website, we'll call it `example.com`. Traffic to this site is good and am happy about where it is headed. Now, I'm launching a new product and have a tech requirement which would only allow it to be a subdomain, we'll call it `newproduct.example.com`.

I plan on doing a lot of marketing and increasing user engagement on the subdomain. I think the traffic on the my subdomain will increase several fold and will always be higher than the main website (`example.com`).

My worry is, from a SEO point of view, am I doing the right thing opting for a subdomain? With reduced traffic on the main website and higher traffic on the subdomain, will my SEO be affected?

Comment: Short answer. No, it will not going to affect.

Comment: Why would having a page or a subdomain that ranks highly ever be an SEO problem?   That sounds like an SEO success.      If somebody searches for "NewProduct" then they should find your subdomain and not your home page.   Of course it should rank higher.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it will hurt in SEO point of view. As you said you are getting much traffic on sub domain as comparative to main domain, so it could be possible on your sub domain you have produced good content or stuff for your users as compare to main domain

Answer (score 0):

Sub domains are treated pretty much as completely separate from the domain. Your best bet would be to place the product on the new site as a sub directory. More and more people are looking to consolidate sub domains to benefit from the combined link equity as SEO landscapes become more competitive.

Point no5 under the section " SEO best practices" is a good source to back this statement up https://moz.com/learn/seo/domain

Answer (score 0):

I think Google considers example.com and newproduct.example.com different websites. And I don't think it popularity of subdomain will have a bad effect on domain, although it may have a good effect if you place a link of domain on subdomain.

Comment: [Google does not usually consider subdomains to be separate sites](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo).   A penalty on a subdomain can effect the main domain.    Subdomain results can push the main site out of the search results.     When it is clear that the same person or company controls both, Google tries to treat them as a single site.

Answer (score 0):

**Google will consider both example.com and newproduct.example.com to be separate properties all together**

So though both will continue to exist separately and index differently, both will surely affect each other.

As new product continue to be a part of main site, it would be better to make it a new directory and promote that:

Example make example.com/newproduct , example.com/newproduct/.... as new urls

The main domain authority of example.com will help its sub-directory rank better and a well ranked/indexed sub-directory will help its parent rank better.

But if they are created as a subdomain, the whole game changes and you need to manage/control a lot of things like stopping same page to be indexed/crawled from different domains, seo health checkup of both domains etc

We also had product.example.com and example.com kind of a seo structure and once we moved to example.com as main domain and all under it, we got great seo benefits.