# Subdomains and Search Engine Indexing

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

Since I am new to all this stuff. I have a main site, example.com. On that site I am going to offer a few services and products and for each thing I am thinking to create a separate subdomain. For instance `my-awesome-hr-product.example.com` etc.

Now question has two parts

- If I add a site via Search Console and add the root url `my-awesome-hr-product.example.com` to the index, is it Ok or I will have penalty, assuming of sub domain link is added on main site (example.com) or not.
- In terms of promoting my sub-domain, what step should I take to rank it up?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating subdomains for SEO reasons.   See: [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)  Use subdomains only in cases where the hosting has to be different for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

- No, you won't have penalty.
- You can think your subdomain as a new site and behave according to this.

e.g. It is easy to see lots of websites which are their subdomains or subdirectories are more popular than the main website. ([tympanus.net/codrops](https://www.tympanus.net/codrops) is a good example.) You can also see Google has moved fonts.google.com to www.google.com/fonts.

Google has moved fonts directory back to [fonts subdomain](https://fonts.google.com).