# Are there any downfalls to having my Google Adwords landing pages on a subdomain?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, subdomain, google-ads

I wish to keep all of my landing pages on a subdomain, like `c.domain.com`. Visitors end up on those landing pages by clicking a Google ad.

A follow-up question to this, is: How do I properly set this up in Google Analytics? I'm thinking that traffic to the campaign pages may very well lead to the main site, even though that isn't the intention.

The reason I have for keeping the campaign pages on a subdomain, has to do with the CMS, i.e. it's a purely technical reason.

Answer (score 2):

**Subdomain or subfolder**

It depends. You say "Visitors end up on those landing pages by clicking a Google ad."

By this, do you mean that you users will *only* reach those pages by clicking on ads? And that you then don't really need these pages indexed? Because if that is the case you can of course `noindex` the pages and put them on whichever subdomain you like.

If the landing pages would also be useful to a user clicking through from another site or organic results, then it's generally better to use a subfolder. See [the answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo) linked to in Stephen's comment.

**Tracking in Google Analytics**

Assuming you do use a different subdomain, a visitor will land on *c.domain.com* and may click through to *www.domain.com*. When they do this, their session on *c.domain.com* will end, and a new one will begin on the *www.domain.com* property. Setting them up as different properties won't fix this problem.

Instead, set up cross-domain tracking. This means the same tracking code is used across the different subdomains. There are a few different ways to set that up—see the official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342)—but if in doubt about how to proceed I'd strongly recommend using Google Tag Manager (described in detail on that page).

Once you've done that, all the hits on the subdomain and the main domain will belong to the same GA property. So you need to watch out for page paths.

Google Analytics only reports page *paths* by default, so when you look in the landing pages report you won't see *c.domain.com/some-page* listed there, but just */some-page*. There's no way to distinguish whether the page was on *c.domain.com* or *www.domain.com*. You can get around this in one of two ways:

1. Give your landing pages on *c.domain.com* distinctive page paths. For example, don't have a `/contact` page on the subdomain *and* on the main domain, because this will make your reports difficult to interpret.
2. Get domain names to appear in your reports, by consulting [this section](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342#Next) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of having c.domain.com, do for www.domain.com/c - The reason is that Google treats each subdomain as a new property and you will lose out on a lot of SEO sauce as well.

If you want to set it up on GA, you will have to setup each subdomain on Google Analytics as a new property.

Comment: That isn't always true: [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)