# How to point a subdirectory URL of a static website to a Heroku app?

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, heroku

I have a static website, hosted on BlueHost and a React/Express app hosted on Heroku. I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this.

Access static site with: `staticsite.com`

Access Heroku app with: `staticsite.com/app`

What particular settings should I be looking into for setting up this structure?

Comment: A subdomain would be easier to point to a separate server through DNS settings, but it is possible to port a subdirectory via proxy. Take a look at [this answer on How to implement WordPress in a subdirectory, hosted on a different server?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/108145/95015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tshimkus mentioned, to serve Heroku from a subdirectory you will need to reverse-proxy it from the server that is hosting your domain. This is a much more complicated setup for arguably minimal gain, and depending on how your pages are cached in the reverse proxy, it can introduce latency to the request having to go through multiple hops before reaching the user.

It would be much easier (trivial) to just serve Heroku from a subdomain.

Alternatively, you could consider serving your static site as part of your Heroku app, from your main domain.