# Is there way to force Google to think that sub domain as totally separated are from main domain?

Tags: seo, google, domains, subdomain, penalty

Is there way to force Google to think that sub domain as totally separated are from main domain?

This is the situation. We have a web design agency. We have made some online tools for public.

1. Free Image hosting Service
2. SEO Tool
3. Online Calculator and many more..........

Getting separated domains and renewing them quite expensive as well as manging them is also time consuming work.

So we are going to use sub domains. Assume that one main domain is `example.com`

So domains will be.

1. `imagehostingservice.example.com`
2. `seotool.example.com`
3. `calculator.example.com`

The problem I have,

If there is penalty for `example.com` it will affect to other websites also because they are sub domain of `example.com`.

If that thing happen it will waste lots of our time effect to build those tools.

If Google consider our main domain and 3 sub domains are totally separated domain our problem will be solved.

So is there any solution?

Comment: The flip side of having your domains all related is that they share reputation.   The combined reputation is greater than the individual reputation.   Just don't do things on any of them that will attract penalties.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The only problem I am fear is main site has a section which works like Reddit.... There is no internal pages like reddit internal pages which others can comment. But there around 50 pages like https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/... Those pages have no content but there many links for other websites and blogs... Yes... all links are no-follow. Should I fear?

Comment: *Is there way to force Google to think that sub domain as totally separated are from main domain?* Short answer? No. It may be you will want to move the user created content to a sub-domain if there is a problem or police it tightly.

Answer (score 2):

Google considers sub domain as separate website but one common thing with it is that default ip address which is legally not possible to change or use as proxy ip for such purpose. So... **NO legal method to force search engines** like google to consider subdomains as separate domain.

Whereas possible you can consider Massimiliano Rubino's suggestion.

Two things for your consideration if you are not able to accept his suggestion:

1. Most of the time Sub Domains affects if Main Domain get penalty.
2. If your single Sub Domain get penalty then it won't affect your Main Domain but has some exceptions
3. But if your Multiple Sub Domains has several kind of penalties by Search Engines then your Main Domain will affect definitely.

Comment: Sub-domains are **NOT** considered separate websites by Google.   Google usually considers all the content under a domain (even on subdomains) as part of the same site owned by the same person or business.   See  [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

Comment: I have studied many articles which says that google consider subdomains as different site one of it is https://ignitevisibility.com/why-blogs-on-subdomains-are-basically-worthless-for-seo/

Comment: I would like to know right thing if possible plz, share related link from google.

Comment: Google has never officially said one way or the other.  Years ago they appeared to be considered separately.  Google didn't group results from different subs in the search results meaning the whole page could be from one domain.  That isn't true today. Google is clearly recognizing that in most cases subdomain are very related.

Comment: In case of Mobile friendly design Google allows and considers subdomain as part of main domain by the help of its canonical url settings for responsive and by using some options in Webmaster. But I don't found any option for other kind of subdomains for example. blog or other in Webmaster tool by which we can specify google that "blog.site.com" is part of "site.com" and related to same business. If you know so plz share...

Comment: You don't need to specify that.   Google knows that most subdomains are part of the main domain.    There are probably some things you can do to make it even clearer.  For each of them:  Add to Search Console, use the same analytics code, use the same copyright, link to the same contact page and terms of service,

Comment: But what if I have various purpose which varies from main domain business area like blogging, ecommerce, niche marketing etc. Do I get SEO advantage for all sub domains by google considering it as part of main domain?

Comment: It is very common to have things like blogs and ecommerce shops on subdomains.   There is no SEO downside to doing it that way.

Comment: You can simply point any subdomain at any IP address you like in the DNS settings. So to suggest it is "legally not possible" to have a different IP between subdomain and root domain is patently false.

Comment: Subdomains can point to different IPs or a single one. Regardless, Google will treat each subdomain as a separate website (examples of this include Wordpress.com, Blogger.com, etc.). The key here is that they shouldn't link each other if you want them to be considered separate entities.

Answer (score 1):

Google consider a sub domain as a completely different website for his domain. So if your domain rank well in "cars (for example) a sub domain can rank well in "pets care".

But Google still know if 2 or more website are related even if them are on different domains and different servers, easier if it is a sub domain.

So as from the comment of Stephen Ostermiller if you do something wrong will be partially reflect on the main domain, as well as if you do something good.

If you want to keep a clear image and easy navigation system on your main site without mess up with link between subdomains and tools and blogs or whatever, I can suggest you to have only 2 domains (so not so expensive): 1 is the main one, for your web design agency, the other one you can use for tools and experiment and anything you like. This not for Google but also for your pace of mind that keep separate the "experiment" (for example maybe in the future you will shut down a tool).
example:

main site: `yourmaindomain.example`

other services:
`yourseconddomain.example/imagehostingservice`

`yourseconddomain.example/seotools`

`yourseconddomain.example/calculator`

And keep them in 2 different cPanel, not for SEO reason but to keep easy the navigation of the main website without using subdomain that maybe point to folder also reachable from other URL (example: you have a subdomain -sub.example.com- that point to public_html/subdomainfolder. That folder you can reach by `sub.example.com` but also from `example.com/subdomainfolder` and this can generate confusion when search engine try to map your site.

Then you can link to each other some pages if need.

Comment: Sub-domains are **NOT** considered separate websites by Google.   Google usually considers all the content under a domain (even on subdomains) as part of the same site owned by the same person or business.   See  [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

Answer (score -1):

Nope, There is no way to indicate google that sub-domain is "totally" different or independent. By default google considers sub-domain as separate domain but there are some other factors too, one of that is if your sub-domain found in any kind of malfunctioning activity it will treat your main as well as all other sub-domains as same and will treat accordingly.

In your case my suggestion is to use sub-directory @Rubino suggested. It will give advantage to your all tools to leverage traffic and ranking faster.