# Will buying links pointing to our main domain also help SEO of sub-pages and sub-domains?

Tags: seo, links

If we buy several back links for the home page of the main domain, will it also help the sub-domains and sub-pages of our site?

Comment: Never buy back links! This quite simply does not work.

Comment: Does if they don't sell any other links but the fact is these sites that sell links don't just stop at customer 1 :)

Comment: My purpose was reportage or guest post.

Comment: Using semantics and pattern recognition, search engines can easily determine organic links versus any other. Search engines prefer organic links. Any other link can easily be discounted, ignored, or penalized depending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buying backlinks is risky. Google has stated that manual actions can be taken against your site for doing so.

If you receive backlinks to your domain, your subdomains won't necessarily benefit from it because it might be treated as individual domains depending upon how Google associates your subdomain to your maindomain. The stronger the association between your subdomain and domain, the more link juice the backlink is likely to carry to your subdomain.

If your main domain links to your subdomains it will pass link juice. So whatever backlinks you have pointing to your main domain, those can pass some juice to your subdomains as well.

Comment: For more info about the relationship between the main domain andsubdomains see [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

Comment: My purpose was reportage or guest post.

Comment: I know you have to market your site however you can. Paid advertising is a major way of marketing. I'm just letting you know about Google's warning about this. They even have penalized sites for guest posting backlinks