# Will cross linking three subdomains to each other be good for SEO?

Tags: seo, subdomain, links, multi-subdomains

I have 1 domain with 2 subdomains. for example:

- example.com
- news.example.com
- video.example.com

Would linking these three domains to each other through the menu, content, and pictures with do-follow links for SEO be useful?

[image]

Comment: You should link your sites, just don't be obnoxious about it thinking that it will game the system. Just be natural. It will help in respect to search engines finding your other content. That is where it ends. Of course, this can be good for the users too.

Comment: It would be probably better for news and video subdomains to redirect to example.com/news and example.com/video for SEO but not necessarily functionally better for your server topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SEO purposes, the fewer domains and subdomains you have, the better. Subdomains don't really help boost the main domain and if people link to the subdomains rather than the main domain, you're diluting your influence.

It's a little harder to tell what you should do in your particular case without knowing what specific content and audiences you have. You could use the news and video subdomains as CDNs, and that might slightly help SEO by speeding up the main domain. Or, if they are truly separate websites with different audiences and content, you would be better off setting up completely different domains for them and then linking wherever it seems natural - in the middle of an article or page, not in a sitewide header/sidebar/footer. If you can set them up as separate domains, and also host them on a different block so they are recognized as separate domains, and they truly are separate sites, that could possibly help SEO a bit through the cross-linking, but you'd also have to be building backlinks to all 3 sites rather than just 1, which is a much larger effort.

Comment: If they want to link between them like that, it sounds like it is all one big site.    There is no problem when using subdomains as part of one site, with proper linking they do help boost the main site.   See [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)   I'd say use subdomains sparingly, but there are plenty of good use cases for them.   In this case the news and video may be handled by different CMS or different content services and that would be a perfect use case for subdomains.

Comment: my website is about auto repair shop. my news.example.com is about auto news and video.example.com is about car video. Many sites use subdomains. for example: google.com and ... My problem is Low power to build a site from the first (Mood، Money، Time، Power in SEO ) . For that matter I want to use the subdomain. But do not know the linking method?