# How can we change a subdomain to a subdirectory when we can't host on the same server

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain

I have a client that have a site: `https://www.example.com`. He has a blog on an another provider with a subdomain: `https://blog.example.com`.

The SEO on the two is divided, so I'm wondering what is the better solution to correct this issue.

We cannot bring the blog on the same server than the site.

So we though of something, changing `https://blog.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/blog`.

How can this be achieved, knowing that the blog and the site will not be on the same server?

I have a DNS CNAME record in mind, but is this SEO significant?

Comment: It isn't an SEO problem to use a blog subdomain.  It doesn't "split" anything.  Google sees it as all one site as long as you link between the two in the menus, use the same copyright, and such.   See [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)  Google's John Mueller just reiterated that Google doesn't treat subdomains and subdirectories any differently for rankings.  He says the only difference is they may have different crawl settings and crawl rates.  See my answer to that question for full details.

Comment: What you want may be able to be done but it has some big draw backs in speed and it can't be done just with DNS settings.   You will have to be able to make changes to your servers to make it happen.