# Subdomain to subdirectory forwarding with SEO integrity

Tags: seo, dns, subdomain, godaddy

I've set up a blog on webflow at blog.mysite.com. However, I'd like to have the blog live at mysite.com/blog for SEO purposes. See [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories-best-practices-workers-part-1/) for more detailed thought process.

Cloudflare [solves](https://blog.cloudflare.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories-improved-seo-part-2/) this problem with service workers. However, I'm currently using GoDaddy for my nameservers and would prefer to not switch to cloudflare. How can I accomplish the same goal of keeping domain authority for my blog at mysite.com/blog while still technically hosting my blog at blog.mydomain.com?

Comment: That article says "Google says subdirectories and subdomains are treated the same" but then goes on to say how they differ without citing any studies or sources.   In my experience subdomains work just fine for your blog.   If it is a pain to put it on a subdirectory, you can.  See our question here with my answer: [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53923)

Comment: thanks @StephenOstermiller. I hear you that you can make the blog subdomain work but I'd rather not. Do you have a suggested way of achieving the solution above? Thanks

Comment: I downvoted here because you badly obfuscate names, and this is bad. I downvoted the other one because it is offtopic on StackOverflow. And I feel it is important to show you are asking the same question on multiple sites, because this is not something you are supposed to do. So by all that it gives you ideas on how to improve your question, and that should be helpful.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek it'd be helpful if you were more explicit and edited the question to help clear up where I've "obfuscated names"

Comment: https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/example-domain-cleanup and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller interesting article that uses data to make the case that one should use subdirectories instead of subdomains https://buttercms.com/blog/blog-subdomain-or-subdirectory-hint-one-is-40-better

Comment: What type of server are you using?  Here is a solution for nginx: [Move a blog on a different server from a subdomain to a folder using Nginx](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119529/move-a-blog-on-a-different-server-from-a-subdomain-to-a-folder-using-nginx) and you could do something similar on Apache.

Comment: Please edit this to give more details about your server.  There are lots of different ways to accomplish this, but they depend on your server configuration.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek This is a new user. We should be guiding the new users to success. Before down voting, you should give the OP the opportunity to improve their question or answer. As well, it is not uncommon that an OP asks a question on more than one stack. And while marking questions as duplicate is appropriate, it is not helpful to mark both as duplicate and have them both put on hold. Since this is likely the best stack for the OPs question, it makes sense to have the other question marked as duplicate and leave this one alone with a helpful comment. We are trying to encourage users.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You will notice that I am not new to SE. I know how it works. My point is to encourage users into the behavior you want rather than beating them up. Most users do not use search. Not sure why, however, you can always suggest a search or do one and link the results. We have done that here many times. My comments are directed to guiding you to being a more constructive and gentle user. My comments apply to that end. It is meant to be constructive as I have suggested things to consider. The best reply would have been to find the positive and leave the rest. Cheers!!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I mentioned your involvement in closing the post because you mentioned it. I was trying to be constructive in mentioning that it is far nicer to comment and give OPs the opportunity to fix their posts. You mentioned down-voting as well. This is part of what I am talking about. I am not patronizing you or making any ad hominem comments at all. I am not beating you up either. It just felt to me that a gentler approach might have been warranted. The user I am trying to encourage is you - to be gentler and think of new users. That is my message. Nothing more.

Comment: @user2954587 I have read both posts and I do not see where you have to change your DNS provider nor can I imagine you would have to. It appears that you can implement the service helpers as you wish. Cheers!!

Comment: @user2954587 Is there any requirement of CloudFlare that requires your using their DNS that I am not aware of?

Comment: @closetnoc thank you for your help. I believe it's necessary to also use cloudfalre's nameservers in order to then intercept the traffic and reroute it? When trying to make a worker I get the following error `TLS peer's certificate is not trusted; reason = Hostname mismatch`.

Comment: @user2954587 Changing your nameservers to Cloudflare is what allows us to fully proxy and provision a site. If you can't change to our nameservers, you have two options: found here... https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017421192-Cloudflare-DNS-FAQ#CloudflareDNSFAQ-CanIuseCloudflarewithoutchangingmynameserverstoCloudflare

Comment: @user2954587 You are right. Using Cloudflare's DNS is required for the javascript. There are some options, but it may be best to change your DNS to CloudFlare. Personally, I would not hesitate.The error you are getting is not specific to CloudFlare though it may be related to DNS settings. Cheers!!