# Is it possible to mask a URL?

Tags: url, subdomain, directory, masking

When a user goes to the site and request the following page: myworld.com/blog is it possible to deliver the contents from /blog/ from a different server which is the physical location for blog.myworld.com? Is it possible to mask a subdomain URL to look like it is a subfolder of a domain so Google and users see myworld.com/blog? is this good practice for SEO?

Comment: Hosting a blog an a subdomain is a very common practice and shouldn't hurt SEO.   See [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo/53923#53923)

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure of why you're trying to do this?  Maybe you can add more information.

If you want to pull content from another server or location, there are several ways to do it - virtual directories, RSS feeds, etc (see links below).  However, if you are trying to hide the source of the content from the user, Google would probably interpret that as cloaking which is bad for SEO.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

Comment: We have a domain and a subdomain. The subdomain (blog.myworld.com) lives in a separate domain. The domain (myworld.com) lives in a different domain.  I read in another conversation it is possible to point blog.myworld.com.com to load content from a subfolder on the root myworld.com/blog (subfolder). It's possible to do if the contents live on the same server. However the physical location of the subdomain is in a different server.  How  is it possible to achieve the latter when both are in two different servers?

Comment: @FrancesRosales Virtual directories create directories on one server that pull the content from another physical directory on the network.  They obviously need to be connected with a reliable high speed network connection.  You'll probably have to research your particular web server for implementation procedures and how to make the virtual directory be the home directory for blob.myworld.com.  Read the MS link I provided to get an idea of how MS does it.