# SEO risks factor analysis Moving Blog URLs from SubDomain to SubDirectory

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, site-move

We’re in process to move WordPress blog URLs from subdomains to sub-directory. We aren’t moving blog physically, but using reverse proxy and 301 redirection to do this. What I mean is:

Our main website is e-commerce marketplace which is YMYL site. This is on Windows server. Due to technical reasons, we can’t physically move our WordPress blog to the main website. So we are going to do this setup.

- Blog subdomain URL is https://blog.example.com/ and
- destination sub-directory URL is https://www.example.com/blog/

**Following is technical setup:**

1. Setup a reverse proxy at https://www.example.com/blog/ pointing to https://blog.example.com/
2. Use a 301 redirection from https://blog.example.com/ to https://www.example.com/blog/ with an exception if a traffic is coming from main WWW domain then it won’t redirect. Thus, we can eliminate infinite loop.
3. Change all absolute URLs to relative URLs on blog
4. Change the sitemap URL from https://blog.example.com/sitemap.xml to https://www.example.com/blog/sitemap.xml and update all URLs mentioned within the sitemap.

**SEO Risk Evaluation**

We have individual GA Tracking ID and individual Google Search Console Properties for main website and blog. We will not merge them. Keep them separate as they are.

Keeping this in mind, I am evaluating SEO Risks factors

1. Right now when we receive traffic from main website to blog (or vice versa) then it is considered as referral traffic and new cookies are set for Google Analytics. What’s going to happen when its on the same domain?
2. Which type of settings change should I do in Blog’s Google Search Console?
    **(A).** Do I need to request “Change of Address” in the Blog’s search console property?
    **(B).** Should I re-submit the sitemap?
3. Do I need to re-submit the blog sitemap from the https://www.example.com/ Google Search Console Property?
4. Main website is e-commerce marketplace which is YMYL website, and blog is all about content. So does that impact SEO?
5. Will this dilute SEO link juice or impact on the main website ranking because following are the key SEO Metrices. **(A).** Main website’s Avg Session Duration is about 10 minutes and bounce rate is around 30% **(B).** Blog’s Avg Session Duration is 33 seconds and bounce rate is over 92%

I referred to some of the case studies and guidelines by Google, but there isn’t anything specific related to this case. Need an expert’s advice.

Comment: If it isn't broken don't "fix" it -- a subdomain blog can have fine SEO.  [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)  I've seen some articles where they moved to a directory and got an SEO bump, but nothing that convinces me that it was because of the move.  In every article I've read they have also improved interlinking at the same time.

Comment: yeah, we finally decided to keep it as it is. we gonna keep blog at subdomain itself. Technically it is fesible, but SEO wise its quite risky.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you indicate you no longer need an answer.