# Subdomain vs Subfolder for Billing Software; Specifically Knowledgebase, Downloads, Status Pages

Tags: seo, subdomain, cms, subdirectory

**Intro**

"Subdomain vs Subfolder" Yes this question has been asked many, many, times but I will try to ask this in a way which is not considered a duplicate as my question pertains more to some of the features that most modern billing and automated hosting systems provide.

Please correct me if I am wrong but I have read that when it comes to the search bots, specifically google, subdomains and sub directories are equal. But reading through some Moz articles show that there has been conflicting cases to what Google is claiming; specifically that subdomains can still somewhat act as their own self contained website.

Reading a post on Cloudflare puts it in this way:

> A subdomain is equal and distinct from a root domain.  This means that a subdomain's keywords are treated separately from the root domain.

---

**Current Setup/Question**

Now my question comes from some features billing software offers that I would rather not be seperated from the main domain. Specifically the Knowledgebase but also a download and server status section albeit to a lesser extent.

Currently I have a FAQ page setup on my main subdomain which is www.domain.com (non-www redirects to www). The main bulk of my website is on this main site (the www.domain.com). I have setup a billing system hosted on a different server under a subdomain, lets call it my.domain.com.

I would really like to start using the knowledgebase which is built into the billing software CMS over the current /faq page which isnt running on any sort of CMS. This would make it a lot easier to manage, add, edit any of the information in these sections of the site.

But do I risk losing these keywords that would normally be associated with my main (www.) website because now they would be hosted on the sub domain of my billing CMS?

A solution I thought of was to have my billing software located on the main www. but in a sub directory instead of a subdomain. For security reasons the billing CMS would still be hosted on a different server but I would just setup a reverse proxy for www.domain.com/billing/etc... to load the billing CMS.

Am I way over thinking this?

---

**Direct Questions**

1. Hosting a billing CMS on a subdomain is no issue but would the billing CMS's Knowledgebase pages be associated with my main domain or only the subdomain in which the billing CMS is access from?
2. Is using a reverse proxy to allow access to the billing CMS under a subfolder instead of from a subdomain a good idea?
3. Are there problems or issues that I am just not seeing when it comes to where my FAQ/Knowledgebase, Downloads, Status pages are accessed from?

Comment: Related: [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53923/54214)

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably to use both a subdomain and a subdirectory but redirect the subdomain to a subfolder using a 301 redirect. This would mean that, depending on how you configured your web host, files would be more easily accessible from inside of the website.

Also, using a reverse proxy may be a good idea but it definitely depends on how you configured your webpage. Make sure the reverse proxy system is extremely secure.