# Which of this is search-engine friendly - google?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, subdomain, keywords

Which of this is search-engine friendly - Google?

1. www.example.com/keyword
2. www.keyword.example.com
3. www.example.com/keyword1-keyword2

Please explain the logic behind while answering and rate them.

Give me some more tips about subdomain SEO, like www.keyword.example.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to this question:

[Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

and this one:

[Are page ranks for subdomains independent?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/are-page-ranks-for-subdomains-independent/3495#3495)

My advice is taken from here: (linked from one of the above answers)

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/

"If you’re a newer webmaster or SEO, I’d recommend using subdirectories until you start to feel pretty confident with the architecture of your site. At that point, you’ll be better equipped to make the right decision for your own site."

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be noted that any difference between the configurations you mention is relatively minor.

They are all SE friendly in their own ways but in general:

- Keywords in the top level domain (e.g. www.KeywordExample.com) are given a little more weight.
- Subdomains (e.g. keyword.example.com) and directories (e.g. example.com/keyword) are pretty much the same.
- Subdomains are treated as separate, but usually related, sites.

In short, **don't worry about it**. Just create your site on a suitable domain with unique, relevant content. And remember that the biggest ranking factor in Google is still **links**. Any advantage from one URL configuration over another is insignificant once you have a handful of links pointing to your site.