# Are there benefits of receiving external links from PR 0 or 1 sites for SEO?

Tags: seo, pagerank, links, backlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Effect of adding link from PR1 site to PR0 site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16170/effect-of-adding-link-from-pr1-site-to-pr0-site)

I'm thinking to do some link exchanges with PR0 or PR1 sites which have the related contents as my site. And my link will be in their link page and theirs will be in my link page.

I have read somewhere that 1000 links from PR1 is equivalent to just 1 from PR4.

Are there sill some SEO concerned benefits for doing this?
Or if not above what PR will be worth exchanging links?
Anyway I'm thinking to do it only with related pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fully agree with [@toomanyairmiles's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/29402/4461) - so feel free to mark that as correct, but your question begs some additional questions that come up when this question is asked:

**Q1.** *What is the real benefit of exchanging a link with a PR1 site?*
**A1.** First, there's no such thing as a PR1 site. PR (PageRank) is assigned at a *page* level, not a site level. So if you get a link from the homepage which has a PR value of 1, then you get a share of that.

**Q2.** *What is the value of a "link" page?*
**A2.** Following on from the logic of the first answer, the "link" page might actually have 0 PageRank, so you'd be getting a share of 0. Actually that "link" page might have 10-100+ links on it, so you'd be getting 1/10th-1/100th of 0 - not very much you'd agree.

**Q3.** *What is the value from a link on a "link" page?*
**A3.** Now this can vary wildly, but Google has stated previously that it values 'editorial' links higher than just lists of links (like sidebar links etc), so if your link was contained within contextually relevant (to your link/site) text, then it might be worth something. The reality is that "link" pages are just lists of unrelated (to each other) links and not even related to your site. The algorithmic difficulty to determine this by Google would almost be child's play.

Think of it this way - **Search Value is proportional to Level of Difficulty**. If it's easy to do (get reciprocal links from a link page of another site) then it's of low value. If it's hard to do (get a viral link from major news organisations because you've solved a world problem or reinvented lolcats) then it's going to be high value.

Comment: Thanks for your logical explanation. I understood the basic concept of the link value "If it's hard to do then it's going to be high value." as you say. I probably should take into account @toomanyairmile's answer rather than expecting something from those low quality pages.

Answer (score 3):

At this point in time pagerank is such a small part of Google's calculation that I doubt it will provide any real benefit, especially in a [post Panda SEO world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda).

What you want to avoid is an '[Unnatural Links Penalty](http://www.aboutus.com/how-to-avoid-an-unnatural-links-penalty/)'.

To understand the potential consequences of getting this wrong check out this article by [Barry Schwarz](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-paid-links-14968.html), and this comment by [Google's Johnathan Mueller](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!searchin/webmasters/authorname%3ajohnmu%7Csort%3adate/webmasters/RPlKleYVOXk/-Lb4TE0yuqIJ). Both address the potential work involved in removing the links if Google doesn't like them and flags your site.

Comment: I just read those articles. I should reconsider what I've been trying to do..Thanks.