# Migrating PageRank/rankings from one site to another

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, pagerank, ranking

I've got a client's company site with decent PageRank, backlinks and search engine rankings.

The client wants to change their company name and therefore URL. I will set up a redirect between the old site and the new. But I was wondering, is there a way to tell Google that they are moving while retaining all the rankings?

It is the same people, services, office building, same everything, just rebranded under a different name and URL.

Additionally if there is a way to do this, how does Google handle you buying expired domains and just pointing them onto your site? Could I buy several PageRank 3 domains all relating to the same sector and point them at my site or would Google catch on to this?

Comment: Domains **DO NOT** have **Page** Rank, pages do!

Comment: i suppose the clues in the name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can tell Google you're moving with the [Change of Address](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106) functionality inside [Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).

> If you've moved your site to a new domain, you can use the Change of
>   address tool to tell Google about your new URL. We'll update our index
>   to reflect your new URL. Changes will stay in effect for 180 days, by
>   which time we'll have crawled and indexed the pages at your new URL.

This isn't an entirely clean process though, the site is going to take a hit and will take a little while to recover. You should always maintain 301's from the old site to the new one.

> Important: In order to use the change of address tool, make sure that
>   you've added and verified both your old and new sites, and read the
>   guidelines on moving your site to a new domain. You should be
>   especially careful to use 301 redirects to tell search engines about
>   the new location of your pages. In addition, make sure your original
>   site is not a subdomain (for example, http://newsite.example.com).

As they say, read the [migration guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105) before doing anything. You can find the change of address tool under `Site Configuration > Change of Address` after logging in to webmaster tools.

As I said in the comments, domains don't have PageRank, only pages. You can find answers to your other questions under [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this), [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google) and [Are there benefits of receiving external links from PR 0 or 1 sites for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29398/are-there-benefits-of-receiving-external-links-from-pr-0-or-1-sites-for-seo)