# Better SEO from sub-directory or sub-domain?

Tags: seo, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subdomain versus subdirectory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/subdomain-versus-subdirectory)

I'm working on a site that will act as a sort of companion site or sub-site to my main site.

Is there a difference in SEO of setting it up on a sub-domain or sub-directory?

Comment: I don't know about SEO, but I thought there was a specific use-case for subdomains as opposed to directories.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830446/blog-domain-com-vs-domain-com-blog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851743/when-deploying-a-blog-is-it-best-to-use-a-subdomain-or-a-subfolder-seo-benefits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708860/which-is-better-for-seo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965609/subdomain-vs-subdirectory-in-web-programming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655273/directory-or-subdomain-for-online-store

Answer (score 4):

A subdomain is considered a different domain so no page rank will transfer. If you want to share page rank put it in a subdirectory.

Comment: As far as i'm concerned page ranks are no longer awarded at all by google or am i missing something?

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: Oh sorry it was google who removed it from webmaster tools, so people will stop concentrating on it so much

Comment: -1 as it mentions PageRank (PageRank === ThoughtCancer) - but yeah: a subdomain is seens as a sperate (domain) entity by google (a seperate site)), where a subdirectory is the same site.