# Keyword in sub-domain good or keyword in sub folder? Which is good to manage?

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subdomain versus subdirectory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/subdomain-versus-subdirectory)

Keyword in sub-domain good or keyword in sub folder

```
keyword.abc.com
```

or

```
abc.com/keyword/
```

Which of this two is good to manage?