# example.com/blog vs blog.example.com

Tags: domains, subdomain, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subdomain versus subdirectory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/subdomain-versus-subdirectory)

I'm about to start my own blog (adding it to a domain already owned by me) and I'm wondering what is the best way to set it up. There are two common alternatives for blogs:
`domain.com/blog` and `blog.domain.com`.

My question is: what are the advantages and disadvantages and of each alternative and which one do you think is the best? (in terms of SEO, etc)