# Sub domain or sub-folder?

Tags: seo, search-engines, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)

In terms of SEO is there any advantages/disadvantages to using a sub-domain over a sub-folder:

- www.mysite.com/company
- company.mysite.com

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/3496/60) or [Subdomain versus subdirectory](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1198/60)

Comment: Thanks, didn't show up when I was typing the question.

Comment: No probs, the recommendations work better when there's more text to go on ;)