# SEO and location targeting , sub-domain or sub-directory?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, local-seo, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subdomain versus subdirectory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/subdomain-versus-subdirectory)

With regards to say a national service that has locations based in 10 cities. Each city needs to have individual content, such as blogs, info pages, etc.

Is it better to have (or does it matter):

`chicago.example.com` or `example.com/chicago`

Furthermore if I go with a subdirectory and each city has a blog, how do I enable it so the blog only effects its parent.

For example `example.com/chicago/blog`  should not affect `example.com/washington`

Comment: I've used both techniques with little difference in SEO.