# Optimize SEO: 2 websites or 1 main website and subdomain?

Tags: seo, wordpress, subdomain

I'm working on a WordPress website of a little company, let say: `www.xxx.com`.

Now they want a different website for their workshops.

What is the most optimal construction thinking of SEO?

1) `www.xxx.com` + `www.xxx-workshops.com`

2) `www.xxx.com` + `www.xxx.com/workshops`

3) `www.xxx.com` + `workshops.xxx.com`

Comment: This question is different to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/subdomain-versus-subdirectory I'm wondering what the difference is regarding SEO between 2 domains and 1 domain + 1 subdomain or subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Using a subdirectory will profit from the existing links and "value" of the `www.xxx.com` domain. A new (sub)domain will have a lower ranking in the beginning will need extra work.

As long as the company wants to rank with its page and the workshops are somehow related to the company, you should go for the subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks. So I should go for `www.xxx.com/workshops`? But `workshops.xxx.com` will also profit from the existing links and "value" of the `www.xxx.com` domain or not?

Comment: Search engines usually treat different sub-domains as different things and thus workshops.xxx.com will not profit from existing links. At least not as much as a subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains have been created for needs like you have.

If `xxx` in your domain name is a brand name, it's logical to create `shop.xxx.com` or `workshops.xxx.com`.

Comment: Okay, but will this generate the same amount of traffic as with the total of 2 different domains?

Comment: Subdomains are separated of the main domain. In that case, traffic will be divided between the two websites.