# URL strategy for multilingual website

Tags: url, redirects, seo, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get search engines to crawl my site and see a localised view of my data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2726/how-can-i-get-search-engines-to-crawl-my-site-and-see-a-localised-view-of-my-dat)

I was wondering what would be the best URL strategy for a multilingual website (for an Italy based company).

I was thinking about `example.com/it` and `example.com/en`, not showing any content at `example.com` and redirecting the visitors to the localized site when they try to access `example.com`.

What about buying an additional domain, `example.it`, and then redirecting to `example.com/it`?

Are these good ideas? If so, **regarding of SEO**, which are the best redirect methods for both `example.com` (to `example.com/en` or `example.com/it`) and the additional (if available) `example.it` (to `example.com/it`)?

Comment: nice question, waiting good answers.

Comment: see also: http://serverfault.com/questions/52946/website-strategy-for-having-a-single-site-work-for-multiple-countries/

Answer (score 2):

Google just announced [New markup for multilingual content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). This should make it easier for multi-language sites to deal with translated versions of their website.

Answer (score 1):

All are more or less the same. Depends on technology etc.

Approaches are:

- `example.it`, `example.com` etc.... problem - these reflect countries, not languages. Where do you put English? German (Germany, Austria?)
- `example.com/it`, `example.com/en`, `example.com/de` etc. - basically folders
- `it.example.com`, `de.example.com`, `en.example.com` - subdomains, used for example by wikipedia.

From a SEO point of view there is no difference.

I would go with subfolders or subdomains, NOT with different domains - reason: cookies, common login code etc. is a lot better if you have a common domain to hook them up to.

Comment: Fine, but what about redirect methods for site.com to site.com/it or site.com/en? Is it a good idea to keep site.com empty?