# SEO considerations for multilingual websites

Tags: internationalization, seo, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get search engines to crawl my site and see a localised view of my data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2726/how-can-i-get-search-engines-to-crawl-my-site-and-see-a-localised-view-of-my-dat)

I'm developing a website that will be translated into two languages: English and French. I'm just wondering what the best practices for such a site would be when it comes to SEO?

So far, the website has two root sub-directories, which means URLs look as follows:

- `http://www.example.com/en/home`
- `http://www.example.com/fr/accueil`

And in my `<html>` tag I specify the page language using the `lang` attribute (depending on which sub-directory we're in, i.e. `<html lang="fr">`).

Will this be enough for the site to rank and be indexed correctly in local versions of Google, i.e. English pages to achive the best ranking they can on [google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk/) and the French content to achieve the best rankings it can in [google.fr](http://www.google.fr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you set UTF-8 for all websites Google will understand the primary language of each page and will rank it better on its national engines. Nevertheless, I'drecommend to purchase national domains .FR, .DE if you seriously consider multilingual SEO. SE rank *site.de* higher than *site.com/de*

Comment: That's good to know. Unfortunately, I'm not in control of the domain as it's for a client, and the client has procured and provided only the `.com` domain.

Answer (score 1):

Google just announced [New markup for multilingual content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). This should make it easier for multi-language sites to deal with translated versions of their website.