# Would an English site's rank increase if you added other languages?

Tags: seo, ranking, multilingual

My question is similar to this question: [How can I get search engines to crawl my site and see a localised view of my data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2726/how-can-i-get-search-engines-to-crawl-my-site-and-see-a-localised-view-of-my-data)

However, I know that the obvious statement of multiple languages increases the number of impressions your website will recieve due to the large target audience. But is there any evidence that it will increase the number of impressions received on a particular language?

For instance, if I have an English website and I then introduce Spanish, German, and French, is there any evidence that your rank would increase in the UK? In other words, is this a ranking factor, and if so, is it an important factor?

Comment: You'd Spanish, German and French sections of the site will rank better because of the authority of the domain, this is fact and happens for everyone. However if the site is new then it's little to zero gain. Also, translations are not treated as duplication.

Comment: @bybe So because of authority the english section would increase in rank due to the possitive effects that the spanish and german sections would have? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions rolled into one, I'll answer them in turn with my understanding of best practices, see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209 and https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192 for detailed instructions.

1. Your rank in the UK will not increase if you add European languages, however if done properly it will in search results for those languages :)
2. Use 'rel=canonical' on all pages/urls in all languages
3. You should have 'rel-alternate-hreflang' alternates for all languages including the original English. If you already have the English pages indexed in Google, etc they will probably count those as the reference pages with the original content.
4. Panda and Penguin site rankings aside, each page is ranked on it's own merits according to it's relevance to the users search query. Just focus on producing quality content and translations.

Comment: I've had to amend the question if you want to change your answer to make it more relevant to the question.