# Building multiple websites with different domain names or single website with multiple language folder

Tags: seo, pagerank, link-building

Which one is better for increasing PageRank:

1. Hosting multiple websites of different languages and interlink them
2. Host single website and create multiple language pages and interlink them

Comment: Related but not duplicate: [How should I structure my urls for both SEO and localization?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44289/14543)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

If it is a duplicated content, ie, same content, but in another language, I think you should build just one domain, and use a

```
www.domain.com/en/pageName.html
www.domain.com/fr/pageName.html
```

structure.

However, if the content changes substantially according to locale, I think it is better use subdomains like:

```
en.domain.com/pageName.html
fr.domain.com/pageName.html
```

This because subdomains are proper for claiming a full subsection, with different type of content in they, and this structure improve the indexability for crawlers.

Answer (score 2):

Host a single website with multiple language packs. If you host multiple different websites with a different language then your PR will be divided between the sites.

Comment: It's also much more work to promote multiple sites, and the PR/trust will not flow across the sites easily enough to compensate for this.