# Moving one site in Webmaster Tools to more than one site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I structure my urls for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

I have a Question and Answer site about immigration. now I divided it into 2 sites:
**mysite.co.uk**
about immigration to UK
**mysite.com**
with sub domains for every country, Like: *australia.mysite.com* , *sweden.mysite.com* , ...

now I had moved All the content from my first site into .co.uk and .com site and it's sub domains to fill theme.

I now that Google will detect my new 2 sites as duplicate of first on and it is very bad for SEO. and I don't think Google webmaster tools has a tool for it.
so Please Guide me how to fix this problem.

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Comment: You didn't even read the question, and closed it as duplicate. stupid.