# What is better with 3 languages: domain-lang.org x 3, domain.org/lang or lang.domain.org?

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I structure my urls for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

I have three domains for similar content in three languages. One in each.

I have now been told that the languages are better off as subdomains or even as sections. My question is, thus, what is best from a SEO point of view:

- domain-**lang**. com/
- **lang**. domain. com/
- domain. com/ **lang**/

Answer (score 0):

domain. com/lang/ is considered the best for SEO purposes

why not others? because they are not different sites.
they are the same site in different language