# multilingual mobile site and google seo

Tags: mobile, seo, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I structure my urls for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

What's the preferred SEO compliance for a mobile website that is multilingual ?

I have -

web:

```
en: http://mysite.com
fr: http://fr.mysite.com
es: http://es.mysite.com
```

mobi:

```
http://m.mysite.com
```

Should I use http://m.fr.mysite.com for my mobile french version ?

Nothing is specified on google blog for mobile : http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html

Answer (score 0):

According to me, if you can buy .mobi domain for your site that contains mobile version of your whole website and redirect user based on browser they are using (i.e mobile browser or desktop browser) it will help more to manage the each version of the website.

apart from this, you can also go with fr.mysite.com/m/ for french version and so on..

Find more information about mobile friendly website by official google webmaster blog: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2012/06/recommendations-for-building-smartphone.html