# Website promotion by country

Tags: seo

I have two domains, one for UK and another for Australia. I want keep same design and content on both websites the same and I want to promote them country wise.

My question is: can I keep same content on both?   Is there a technique or tag for this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You will get penalized for duplicate content.

Comment: Google say that duplicate content is not penalised when on country-specific sites. "Websites that provide content for different regions and in different languages sometimes create content that is the same or similar but available on different URLs. This is generally not a problem as long as the content is for different users in different countries."

Answer (score 1):

Having regional websites with duplicate content is fine with Google.  You will **not** get penalized by Google if you do it right.  You may want to change the content slightly for different word spellings, different prices, and different currencies.

To do so properly:

- Use a similar URL structure in two different folders, sub-domains, or domains.
- Add both sites (separately) to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).  Go to "Configuration" -> "Settings" and set the geographic targeting correctly for each.  If you use a `co.uk` domain and a `com.au` domain, this will have been done for you automatically.
- Use [rel alternate links with hreflang attributes](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077) between the pages on the two sites.

See [this wiki answer for more information on how to structure your urls for regional sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44289/14543).