# SEO for duplicate sites with multiple domain extensions

Tags: seo, google, domains

I am running business in different nations and I got domains for example

```
www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.us
www.mydomain.ca
www.mydomain.uk
www.mydomain.com.au
```

So, if I run same website with same content (of course there will be little changes like address, etc.) as all these domains has same content will it be considered as spam or will the domains rank well as per the country?

Also, is there solutions if Google considers this as spam.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Google does not consider those as spam.

However, it is likely that one of the domains will have a much higher ranking than the others (i.e. one may have a PR of 6, when the others have a PR of 2).

It may be difficult to get the PR 2 pages higher. But I did not have that goal on my end in that situation...

Answer (score 1):

Google didn't consider it as spam. below is the official google video with the answer. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo

Answer (score 0):

If you are correctly using [rel="alternate" hreflang= meta tags or sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587), then it shouldn't matter if you have mostly similar content. One of Google's examples is just like your question:

> Your pages have broadly similar content within a single language, but
>   the content has small regional variations. For example, you might have
>   English-language content targeted at readers in the US, GB, and
>   Ireland.

More info here: [Googles' rel="alternate" hreflang="x guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587)

Comment: hreflang is for serving different content based on location and language. This is not what this question is about. The question is specifically asking about the same website on multiple domain TLD's.

Comment: From his question I gathered that he has a company that does business in these different locations and thus has a site for each location he serves; which is a valid use of hreflang as mentioned in Google's guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

Running a website with duplicate content is going to have negative consequences, regardless of the domain's TLD. Your websites would perform better if you served unique content on each of them.

There may be an advantage to only allowing the indexing of the relevant TLD in the country search engine however (i.e .com.au in Google Australia) - I'd have to test that to be certain if this would be a workaround to duplicate content though.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect.  You can have the same content on different TLDs without penalty from Google.  See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization

Comment: Err... What are you even replying to...? I didn't even say that you can't nor mention a Google penalty.

Comment: I was replying to "Running a website with duplicate content is going to have negative consequences, regardless of the domain's TLD."  -- There are SEO benefits to duplicating content for regional sites, not negative consequences.

Comment: Providing the TLD's target the intended country and the wording is localised for that country (i.e UK/US spellings) then it is unlikely to cause a problem because Google's algorithm isn't focusing on multi-TLD's for the same business in the same way it is on the similar/duplicate sites on the same TLD. I disagree that there is SEO benefit, it's just unlikely to be considered spam if legitimately targeting... Source: [Matt Cutts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo). I think you've read more into my answer than I intended and don't agree with the downvoting of it personally.

Comment: I did also go on to say that there "may be an advantage to TLD / SE targeting" but this is inconclusive. As a general rule of thumb, duplicate content should be avoided for the most apart where possible.