# Cross-domain linking for a multi-nation, multi-language site?

Tags: seo, domains, duplicate-content, language

I have a website, that is available in, let's say, 3 countries (with data specific to each country), and provide users the posibility to see every website in each of the 3 primary languages of those countries plus English.

Example url structure:

```
company.es (default language "ES")
  company.es/en - (Spanish data in English language)
  company.es/de - (Spanish data in German language)
  company.es/fr
company.de (default language "DE")
  company.de/en - (German data in English language)
  company.de/es
  ..
company.fr (default language "FR")
  ..
etc.
```

I also want to increase the ranking for each newer TLD, using links from the already established ones.

The issue is that I target some users from Spain to use the German website (in Spanish language), so therefore I have links from a country to all countries (keeping the language), e.g. `company.es` links to `company.de/es` .

I want Google to understand the fact that there is different data on each top level domain, and that country-specific data is available in every language.

Does my current linking scheme support that?

**And more importantly, does Google see pages like `company.de` and `company.es/de` as duplicate content?**

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#3) on Google Webmaster Help, I shouldn't be worried about duplicate content because Google treats them as targeted towards different users, but does that still apply in the case mentioned above?

> Duplicate content and international sites
>
> Websites that provide content for different regions and in different
>   languages sometimes create content that is the same or similar but
>   available on different URLs. This is generally not a problem as long
>   as the content is for different users in different countries. While we
>   strongly recommend that you provide unique content for each different
>   group of users, we understand that this may not always be possible.
>   There is generally no need to "hide" the duplicates by disallowing
>   crawling in a robots.txt file or by using a "noindex" robots meta tag.
>   However, if you're providing the same content to the same users on
>   different URLs (for instance, if both example.de/ and example.com/de/
>   show German language content for users in Germany), you should pick a
>   preferred version and redirect (or use the rel=canonical link element)
>   appropriately. In addition, you should follow the guidelines on
>   rel-alternate-hreflang to make sure that the correct language or
>   regional URL is served to searchers.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#3

I have also read [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization) and went through most of the links, but I don't think it applies for my particular case when there are different TLDs with similar content (but different data e.g. local listings) in same languages.

Comment: In addition to the complexity of your multi-regional and multilingual site organisations, it would be unclear to us how much the "data" differentiates the content between `company.es/de` and `company.de`, making this question difficult to answer in regards to duplicate content. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Think of classified listings, but without any user-generated text. Just specs, values, labels that can easily be translated. And of course, a listing is specific to a country (tied to a physical object & address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question states, they are websites using the same application and maybe the same look and feel (template); they work exactly the same way.

First, you must set `Geographic target` in `Google Webmaster Tools => Site Settings`, for every site according to its locale.

#### Different content for different geographic targets.

If your classified listings, and websites in general, are completely different in regards of content then:

Do not include `rel="canonical"` pointing to another `ccTLD` URL, they are different sites for different audiences, pages are different from site to site, not duplicate content.
Do implement `rel-alternate-hreflang` between pages in the same site that targets different languages, if they are a translation of each other.
As an example, for your `company.es` homepage you should add these links (into the `<head>` element):

```
<link rel="alternative" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://company.es" /> <!-- Self referencing -->
<link rel="alternative" hreflang="en-ES" href="http://company.es/en" />
<link rel="alternative" hreflang="de-ES" href="http://company.es/de" />
<link rel="alternative" hreflang="fr-ES" href="http://company.es/fr" />
```

Add a resource such as "Change your location" for letting visitors to jump from one target location (site to site) to another. You are already doing this.

#### Same content per language on different `ccTLD`'s, not a translation between languages.

If your classified listings, and websites in general, are the same in regards of content per language, i.e. company.es and company.de/es display the same content:

Do include `rel="canonical"` pointing to your preferred URL, they have the same content, only one of them should be the master.
This way, `company.de/es`, `company.en/es`, `company.fr/es` should contain (into the `<head>` element):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://company.es" />
```

Take into account that these links should be added per page.

**Some references:**
[Creating the Right Homepage for your International Users](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your.html).
[Multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192).
[Use canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?rd=1).
[Help Google serve the correct language or regional URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077).