# Would this be considered duplicate content for a multi-language site, and is it necessary to redirect by language?

Tags: seo, redirects, canonical-url, multilingual, rel-alternate

Our company now has 2 domains linked to one FTP:
`site.lt` and `site.eu`

- In the `.lt` site, we show the content in the local language
- In the `.eu` site, we show foreign languages like `site.eu/lv`.

1). My first question is if pages like:

`http://site.lt/oliver-weber-auskarai-symbol-9919`

`http://site.eu/lv/oliver-weber-auskarai-symbol-9919`

will be considered duplicates by Google if they have:

- Same title
- Same description
- Different language body
- Same body description

Currently in the `<head>` section we use alternate tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lt-LT" href="http://site.lt/oliver-weber-auskarai-symbol-9919" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lv-LV" href="http://site.eu/lv/oliver-weber-auskarai-symbol-9919" />
```

and canonical links to default local language pages to avoid duplicate penalties:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://site.lt/oliver-weber-auskarai-symbol-9919"/>
```

But I think that canonical links will not let us get indexed with other languages with `site.eu`. Should we not use canonical links?

2). The second question is:

Is it necessary to redirect users/bots to languages by IP or HTTP language header? Can Google add a penalty for this? Or maybe this will be better?

I had read a lot of information and suggestions about these questions, but all them seem to be different.

Comment: Just wondering why `site.it` and `site.eu/lv` have the same "title", "description" and "body description"? Aren't they supposed to be different languages? What's the difference between "description" and "body description"?

Comment: Everything is answered in [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: @w3d "title", "description" and "body description" suppose to be in different languages, but we have a lot off pages and I think it took almost a several month while we translate all pages, but our essential pages are translated and we what to be indexed whit them in google. Description is meta-description in head element and body description is product description in body. element.

Comment: See also: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 1):

If you have 'same' pages translated in different languages, their title and description should be translated too. Otherwise, this will be confusing to users and to search engines too.

In other words, the title and description for `http://site.lt/oliver-weber-auskarai-symbol-9919` should be in `"lt-LT"`.

If you don't use canonical, there is indeed a risk of (near) duplicate content between `http://site.lt/` and `http://site.eu/lv`. It is most probably not going to trigger a penalty, unless you have hundreds of pages like that, but it is definitively going to confuse search engines and hurt your ranking. Have one page with the proper translation and set `rel="canonical"` to that page on other pages showing the same content.

Regarding notifying search engines about other translations, using `rel="alternate" hreflang="lt-LT"` is enough. If there is a `rel="canonical"` element on the target page, they will handle it properly. No worry.