# Would it hurt my rankings to have the same URL display similar content depending on the visitor's country?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, googlebot

I manage a website that has different Web pages that use the same URL structure, and I don't use `= & ?` But depending on your location we will show you different links. Let say you are in the UK and you are on the page `men/Polo.com`, since you are in the UK it might show darker Polo pages and you might like to click on it, and if you are in the US, it will show different links.

Also the page `men/Polo.com` uses the same URL structure and the same content. I was wondering if that could hurt my rankings cause I don't know which link the Googlebot will crawl.

Answer (score 1):

It of course depends on the server location for Googlebot. If your script will see that the Googlebot server is in the UK, then the Googlebot will see the UK links sheet. But I think you can easily decide which version of site the Googlebot will crawl. Your code can check if it's the Googlebot and then do what you want.

About links, I think that if the Googlebot from UK will grab them for UK visitors then the Google search engine will show those links only for UK locations in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

See: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

[Google just announced that Googlebot will send the `Accept-Language` header and crawl from different geographic locations](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/01/crawling-and-indexing-of-locale.html).  However, Google still recommends that you have separate URLs for different content for different countries