# Where should webhosting be located when focusing on the US and EU markets?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, looking-for-hosting

I want to build a website with focus on the US and EU markets; and customers.

Where should the hosting be located for such a case so the website does not suffer high loading time? (Do not include other aspects as website design, amount of content on it etc, but pure hosting decision with only 1 location, no mirroring).

Comment: Why one location?   Creating `eu.example.com` and `us.example.com` can have lots of advantages.

Comment: I don't understand much that example, but let's say it should be low-cost solution. Can you maybe elaborate on your thoughts e.g. what advantages etc? I want to learn so maybe there'll be something I missed and would be beneficial.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If the content is the same, will this not have a negative impact?

Comment: Duplicating your content for users in different countries is allowed.  It doesn't have negative impact.   See the "Internationalization and Geo Targeting" section of [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: See also: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a low-cost solution to serve the same website to users in both continents then https://www.cloudflare.com/ will help keep delays to a minimum. From CloudFlare's own website:

> CloudFlare operates out of 30 data centers around the world. Our CDN
>   automatically caches your static files at our edge nodes so these
>   files are stored closer to your visitors while delivering your dynamic
>   content directly from your web server. CloudFlare then uses a
>   technology called Anycast to route your visitors to the nearest data
>   center. The result is that your website, on average, loads twice as
>   fast for your visitors regardless of where they are located.

They even offer a free tier that will probably suit your needs. This way you can host the origin server wherever is closest to you or whichever side of the Atlantic has more visitors.

<sub>(I'm not affiliated with CloudFlare in any way.)</sub>