# How to perform SEO (Meta-Keywords) for different language?

Tags: seo, meta-keywords

I would like to bring customer from different countries.

So, does google `meta keyword` support another language than `English`?

like

```
<meta name="keyword" content="中国网站, china website">
```

Does google understand Chinese keywords?

Comment: Google hasn't supported the keywords meta tag for years (for any language): https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

Comment: Have a website in that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google certainly understands many languages.   [The Google search engine is available in tens of locales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains).

If you want to bring in visitors that speak other languages you will need to do more than put in meta keywords.   Google doesn't even use meta keywords anymore.   They are spammed too much for Google to pay attention to them.

You will need to:

- Write content in that language (or have your content translated.)  The content has to feel natural to native speakers so machine translation is not an option if you want it to rank in Google.
- Put the content for that language onto its own URLs where it can be found by Googlebot and ranked in the international search engines.  See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: Nice information.