# How to target a website to a non-English country?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, local-seo

I want my website to target a non-English speaking country. I believe that I need to modify something other than the page itself.

I don't speak the language that I want to target. When I used Google for that particular country, Google gives me an English option. I am confused as to what I need to do off page to target that language. Should I target example.com to another sub-directory?

Example: I am targeting in Arabic language. I use google.com.sa and my website is example.com. How to set up Google for that country target?

Comment: Do you have content written in this language and published on your website?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes and also targeting country

Comment: It sounds a lot like you are asking the same thing as here: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization) but I'm not sure what you are expecting off-page.  Do you mean in Google Search Console?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can do to improve your site's visibility in a geographical / linguistic area.

First, you should add hreflang tags to your html code. Hreflang annotations are used by Google as signs for the intended linguistic and geographical targeting of the content.

Two good sources of information:

- [The hreflang Tags Generator Tool](http://www.aleydasolis.com/en/international-seo-tools/hreflang-tags-generator/)
- [Using the Correct Hreflang Tag: A New Generator Tool](https://moz.com/blog/using-the-correct-hreflang-tag-a-new-generator-tool)

Second, you should indicate the geographical targeting in the Search console.

- **Search Traffic > International Targeting**, under tab **Country**

Answer (score 1):

As the poster before me correctly said, meta tags may help google to better rank your site for the targeted audience.

Anyways, to get the site locally ranked it also helps to have a country specific domain but with the new TLDs such as .cloud its a help but not a requirement. Same for IP / CDN, the location of your hosting might matter, but whats more important is loading speed for the country you target. Either get a local host or CDN.

If your site get local attention (mentions and whitehat backlinks in the right context) it should get ranked :).

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to your website SEO, Go to your website . Find meta contents with area target option. Change the targeted country with other countries you wish, then find the targeted area code and edit it to your targeted country.

Comment: this thing also done but now a days to perform off page activity in that country.