# Different domains vs multilingual on one domain

Tags: seo, multilingual, internationalization, marketing, sem

From my understanding, even if it's less powerful than some years ago, the domain name still has a certain importance when talking about ranking for a keyword.

I have a website in two languages, it would be more practical to have everything in one site with the translation and all available. But from a SEO point of view, wouldn't it be better to have two domain names (one the translation of the other), each one with its own language?

Comment: See also: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its just localising the same content I'd lean towards keeping the same domain.

Partly becuase it helps a lot with keeping analytics much more simple, and it will reduce Backlink dilution too. To separate the pages, look into using hreflang.

If its a super low competition niche though and you have limited resources, separate sites is not too bad and there are benefits to EMDs. part of that benefit is that the branded back links you get with your URL as the anchor text will provide slightly more benefit... but remember you will have to work twice as hard to generate two sets of backlinks, one for each region.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little SEO advantage to the keywords in a domain name these days.   Google adjusted their algorithm a couple years ago and now keywords in the domain name give little if any boost.

A domain's reputation, brand, and link profile are still very important for SEO.  So from an SEO standpoint it is almost always better to put all your content on one branded domain name.

You should only consider international domain names if your domain name sounds too "English".   International users often prefer a site that is more native.  That includes on a domain name that makes sense in the local language.   Some brand names work well in many languages, but many do not.