# Language problems with Symfony site in Google

Tags: seo, google, multilingual

I have i 2 language site, based on Symfony3. Currently I have there German and English langs.

The problem is that Google indexing only english version on site and, as I seen in Google Webconsole, some german routes Google also trying to index from en locale. 
What is a problem and how possible to fix it ASAP?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Symfony translation documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) the locale that is used is based on the user's locale.   That is not SEO friendly.  For Google rankings, each language needs to be on its own URL.  Googebot doesn't index the same URL with more than one language.

You need to change your site so that it bases the language on the URL.  That can either be on the domain name (`example.de` vs `example.co.uk`), on the subdomain (`en.example.com` vs `de.example.com`), or on the folder (`example.com/en` vs `example.com/de`).   See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)