# How should I set the Google Search Console language target for the US main site and FR sub-directory?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website with two languages.

- One in English: `www.example.com`
- One in French: `www.example.com/fr`

I have read in different places that it is a good practice to use Search Console > International Targeting and pick up a preferred country. In that case is obvious that those languages are spoken in different countries but my main target audience is clearly in USA and France.

Should I have the two separated in Search console?
`www.example.com` (existing account) choose USA
and "Add a property" for`www.example.com/fr` and choose France

Comment: You shouldn't set `www.example.com` to US because that contains the sub-directory.   You need to move it to `www.example.com/us` first if you really want it targeted.   You can also leave it targeted globally and it will get traffic from every where except France.

Comment: See also: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: @Stephen: I do not seem many people use /us. For instance, just as an example, there is apple.com and then apple.fr that drives to apple.com/fr. That is the most common organization that I see in all the webs and it makes sense. The question is how to reflect that in search console

Comment: Since your sites are two different languages, you probably don't want to do anything in search console.   Setting GEO targeting limits your Google visitors to just one country.  You might want all English speaking visitors to use one and all French speaking visitors to use the other, regardless of country.

Comment: Google has a pretty comprehensive help document on the subject: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en