# Can you tell Google that the same URL is available in 2 languages depending on the browser language?

Tags: multilingual, hreflang, rel-alternate

For example, my home page is available in several language and the language displayed depends on the browser language.

I have added these 2 `alternate` links:

```html
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/lang/en" hreflang="en"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/lang/fr" hreflang="fr"/>
```

Is it possible to tell search engines that the URL `http://example.com` is available both in English and French and the one displayed depends on the browser language?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to tell Google that the same URL is available in either language depending on browser language.    [Google announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/01/crawling-and-indexing-of-locale.html) about 2 years ago that they would start supporting that.

In practice, I don't know of any sites that have implemented it that way and get good SEO rankings.   The recommended way of having a site in multiple languages is still to have separated URLs.   Both Google recommends it that way and I do in [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)