# Multilanguage and Effect on Live Website's SEO

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, multilingual, internationalization

I'm new and learning to SEO. My question is, if I already have a website that has a pretty decent rank with just one language and I wanted to add another language, do it affecting my previous rank?

From what I know, after adding multisite features, Google will reindex the website since it has new link or permalink and the rank on the selected keyword is affected.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you planning to add multi-language features?   Are you planning to create new URLs for the different languages?  For SEO, you should be.

Comment: Hello @StephenOstermiller thanks for responding! To be honest I'm still looking for it. By creating new urls do you mean it was like this: www.example.com/en/ for english language etc ? Or I missed something?

Comment: Yes.  See: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @StephenOstermiller. Based the link you gave me, I'm planning to use subdirectories type. So do it affecting the live website after I use the multilanguage feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any affect on the rankings, i've read cases where people had positive results but thats up to the individual case. What you are doing right now is serving one language content everywhere, if you want to add lets say German language and you are after displaying German content for Germany you should expect better bounce rate and CTR.

Warp up alternative language or region content benefits:

- Increase in indexation
- Bounce rate
- Click-through-rate

Even if you dont get the hreflang correct you wont lose anything as google simply ignores it, but you want to make sure you wont serve the same content otherwise would be considered as duplicate.

To speed up the indexing process i would recommend creating a hreflang sitemap and submit it on Google console.

Short answer: **As long as you serve the content in different language or currency whatever the case is you should have positive out-come**

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So by the comment you post, I shouldn't worry about rank as long as my content is not classified as duplicate by Google? And after I setup multilang on my website, do I need changing or do something with my tools on google side, like google search console or etc ?

Comment: Exactly as long as your content wont be considered duplicate you whould have positive results ranking wise. You will have submit your alternative URL on the Google Console.