# Duplicating website on country subdomains with different prices and currencies OK for SEO?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, internationalization, multi-subdomains

I have a website of online courses.

I have designed my website on 5 subdomain for different countries for price change, for currency change, and for tax change. The content is same on on subdomains.

Will it affect SEO or not?

Comment: Are you using rel="canonical" and geo country codes for each one? If not, then yes, Google may consider it duplicate content. This isn't explicitly bad practice, but you need to make sure Google understands what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google specifically allows duplicate content when targeting the same site to different countries.  Creating subdomains for each country and changing the currency, pricing, and taxes will help your SEO, not hurt it.

You just need to make sure you [tell Google about this targeting](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).   You can either use HTML tags, HTTP headers, or sitemaps to do so.   The link has full details of how to implement them.

Sources:

- [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)
- [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: Yes sir i have subdomain on country base . Thanks for Explaining your Answer Thanks a lot